Deduct real type of object from base class pointer to create copy
I have base class and a lot of classes derived from if. I want to create object copy. Is there a way to deduct real type of object under pointer to base class without dynamic_cast or implementation of createCopy in every derived class?
Something like this:
class Base {
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void fun() = 0;

    Base *createCopy()
    {
        return new /*some way to deduct real "this" type */
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() : Base(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2() : Base(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
};

/* Derived3 - Derived8999 implementation*/

class Derived9000 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived9000() : Base(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
};

int main()
{
    Base *pObj = new Derived9000; // pObj type is Derived9000*

    Base *pCopy = pObj->createCopy(); // pCopy type is Derived9000*
}


"copy" indicates that it should be implemented by the concrete (not base) class. So I guess it should be virtual Base* createCopy() = 0 and then Derivedxxx* createCopy() override. Then you don't need to worry about any type introspections.

Side note Base *createCopy()  no in C++ NEVER return raw owning pointers, return an std::unique_ptr<Base>.

Relevant (possibly duplicate of): Is it possible to clone a polymorphic object without manually adding overridden clone method into each derived class in C++?. Side note: A common way to name a polymorphic-copying function is clone.

You can do this in two ways.
You can store the type in a middle layer like this:
class Base {
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void fun() = 0;
    virtual Base *createCopy() = 0;
};

template <typename Type>
class MiddleBase : public Base {
public:
    MiddleBase(){};
    virtual void fun() = 0;

    Base *createCopy() final override
    {
        return new Type();
    }
};

class Derived1 : public MiddleBase<Derived1>
{
public:
    Derived1() : MiddleBase(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
};

class Derived2 : public MiddleBase<Derived2>
{
public:
    Derived2() : MiddleBase(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
};

/* Derived3 - Derived8999 implementation*/

class Derived9000 : public MiddleBase<Derived9000>
{
public:
    Derived9000() : MiddleBase(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
};

int main()
{
    Base *pObj = new Derived9000; // pObj type is Derived9000*
    Base *pCopy = pObj->createCopy(); // pCopy type is Derived9000*
}

Or IMO a better way you could just let the copy function be overloaded by the specific types and just let each type handle its copy:
class Base {
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void fun() = 0;
    virtual Base *createCopy() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() : Base(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
    Base *createCopy() override {
        return new Derived1();
    };
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2() : Base(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
    Base *createCopy() override {
        return new Derived2();
    };
};

/* Derived3 - Derived8999 implementation*/

class Derived9000 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived9000() : Base(){};
    virtual void fun() { /* impl */ };
    Base *createCopy() override {
        return new Derived9000();
    };
};

int main()
{
    Base *pObj = new Derived9000; // pObj type is Derived9000*
    Base *pCopy = pObj->createCopy(); // pCopy type is Derived9000*
}


First method uses CRTP

You can use virtual functions for this, and also optionally co-varient return types so if you start with a Derived1 type, you get that without the cast.
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual Base* createCopy() const // const, not editing original object
    {
        return new Base(*this); // Use copy constructor for actual work
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Derived1* createCopy() const override
    {
        return new Derived1(*this);
    }
};

It may also be preferable to use smart pointers to avoid the risks of manual new/delete, but unfortunately they would not be considered a covariant return type (see also https://github.com/CppCodeReviewers/Covariant-Return-Types-and-Smart-Pointers which has some suggestions on that).
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> createCopy() const // const, not editing original object
    {
        return std::make_unique<Base>(*this); // Use copy constructor for actual work
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> createCopy() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<Derived1>(*this); // Use copy constructor for actual work
    }
};


With deducing this (C++23), wrapping the smart pointer part is possible in Base, letting just a protected covariant virtual clone method Demo.
